# DbDataReader inner working

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net

We have high load system which consist from SQL Server and .NET apps. 
We are using [DbDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve data from SQL and persist it into JSON to send it across the wire. Our system uses time stamp for all the records that were inserted or modified in order to only send updated data over the wire (each table has extract date time column which gets updated when record is inserted or modified).

In some instances we are seeing that some records would be updated in the database at the same time as we were persisting our JSON. For those records we would not see them in JSON, but showing correct in DB when we check manually. What is even stranger is that other records that have same date time stamp (up to milliseconds the same) are present in JSON. So issue is that next time we retrieve data from DB we only get records above certain date time, which leads to missing couple records that were modified at the same time as JSON was written.

My initial thought is that it could be timing issue that record was not modified when JSON was being written. But how do you deal with this situations?

So my question is what would DbDataReader return only records that were present when DbCommand.ExecuteReader() was executed or it will return records that were modified in database after as well?

Comment: In addition to `ExecuteReader` you are using `reader.Read()`

Comment: What isolation level are the queries running at?  And do you have the READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT database option enabled?

Comment: It will include the records that are in the database when it reads the database.  When it executes the necessary SQL query, it will get what data is in the database, and not anything that gets inserted after.  Am I missing something?  I do not know what "timestamp" you are referring to, but having the same "timestamp (up to milliseconds" is no guarantee that the records were inserted at the same time, not even if that timestamp was generated by an insert trigger.

Comment: When read the SQL server you must use Order By because data isn't stored in order or time.  The SQL Server is does parallel processing to increase speed of a transaction.  It also does locking to prevent one user from reading data while another user is modifying a data location.  So it is possible the while a read query is being performed another user changes the data and the results will show the change.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I don't think we have that option enabled. What does it do?

Comment: @Agapwlesu: That's not what we are seeing. When SQL is executed those records are not present but when it reads those records we see some of them show up in JSON. We generate timestamp as part of insert record method.

Comment: @jdweng: We are ordering them by PrimaryKey but it's not helping us with some records missing.

Comment: If you have a primary key then you have only one row for each key.  Are you saying the key is missing, or the data for the key is wrong?

Comment: @jdweng: Data for the key is wrong. Sorry for misleading description before, i'll update my original question.

Comment: The SQL server is designed to make sure conflicts doesn't occur when updating data, but not when removing items.  First example, when two users are writing to database each user is adding two items the total will be four items added.  Second example, if you have database for a store and you have one item in the database you do not want to two people buying the same item. The second case isn't explicit handled in the SQL Server.  You need a stored procedure that locks the quantity so two users can't purchase same item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> issue is that next time we retrieve data from DB we only get records above certain date time, which leads to missing couple records

It appears you are attempting to extract disjoint subsets of rows from a SQL Server table.  It's not necessary to get into the gory details of transaction isolation levels in this case.

The bottom line is that unless you take a table lock that lasts for at least several milliseconds, you can't use a datetime column to extract disjoint delta's from a SQL Server table.  You see rows as they are committed, not as they are written.  So even if the clock resolution was infinite, transactions can commit in a different order than they read the clock and write the rows.

You *can* use a [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) column for this, as SQL Server increments the value for every transaction.

Or you can build your extract logic to expect overlapping rows.

Or use Transactional Replication, Change Data Capture, or Change Tracking.